# Keras Transfer Learning on More Than 1000 classes

Tags: machine-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

How do you apply transfer learning from models like InceptionV3, ResNet50 which are trained on ImageNet (about 1000 classes) to a problem with more than 1000 classes?

I am using Keras but am open to other solutions. I am familiar with the idea of loading all of the weights of a trained network (like ResNet50 on ImageNet) except for the top (final classification layer with 1000 units) and then connecting the end of the network to other layers that I can specify (fully connected layers, pooling, etc.). However, the layers prior to the final layers in many of these networks have less than 3000 units, so adding a layer that is more than 3000 units will be an expansion layer, kind of like a decoder in an autoencoder. Normally, I have seen the final layers decreasing in size. What is the best way to approach this?

The example in Keras applications is:

```
from keras.applications.inception_v3 import InceptionV3
from keras.preprocessing import image
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Dense, GlobalAveragePooling2D
from keras import backend as K

# create the base pre-trained model
base_model = InceptionV3(weights='imagenet', include_top=False)

# add a global spatial average pooling layer
x = base_model.output
x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
# let's add a fully-connected layer
x = Dense(1024, activation='relu')(x)
# and a logistic layer -- let's say we have 200 classes
predictions = Dense(200, activation='softmax')(x)
```

Comment: What is the actual programming problem here?

Comment: I am trying to solve an image classification problem where I have more than 3000 different objects to classify.

Comment: Yes, that is clear, but what is the issue? I don't see any issue with that number of classes.

Answer (score 2):

**Simple:**
In your code example simply change this line:

```
predictions = Dense(200, activation='softmax')(x)
```

where you input instead of 200 any number of classes you want to train on, e.g. say you have 3000 classes. Then this would be:

```
predictions = Dense(3000, activation='softmax')(x)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is called fine tuning a keras model. You should remove the last layer of the trained model and then for each layer you have to make the weights update false by using:

```
layer.trainable=False
```

After that you can add your custom layer

Eg: Add a dense layer with more than 1000 classes if you want and train it. Then, you can update the weights of the final layer during the training process

For more help refer to this video [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oDHpqu52soI&index=13&list=PLZbbT5o_s2xrwRnXk_yCPtnqqo4_u2YGL)
cheers :-)

Comment: That makes sense, thank you. I am still wondering whether it is okay to have more classes than units in the previous layer.

Comment: Yeh there can be down sides but it doesn't effect so much.this is the only way to do it.if you are going to change the previous layers also,the quality of the model will loss

Comment: @Dulmina if you can a code example it would be very helpful.